# Where are these libraries from

Tags: java, enterprise-library

I have a bunch of libraries missing in eclipse from a project. Doe anyone know where these jars are from?

```
adobe-livecycle-client.jar
adobe-bmc-client.jar    
adobe-convertpdf-client.jar
adobe-distiller-client.jar
adobe-encryption-client.jar
adobe-formdataintegration-client.jar
adobe-forms-client.jar
adobe-generatepdf-client.jar
adobe-jobmanager-client-sdk.jar
adobe-livecycle-client.jar
adobe-output-client.jar
```

Comment: Sounds like a question my friend Google can help with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are part of Adobe Livecycle:
http://www.adobe.com/products/livecycle/

I have no idea how that is sold, but there seems to be an SDK on the download page:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/livecycle/downloads.html